# How to obtain keys to decrypt JWE from Integrity API with Google Cloud Console

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play-integrity-api

I have an Android application which uses Integrity API with Google Cloud. This method is described [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#apps-exclusively-distributed-outside-google-play).

I need to implement server side offline verification for JWE token which requires decryption and verification keys from Play console. [An example of verification](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-locally).

Documentation also says, that for local verification I should get keys from Play console. As long as Integrity API token generation is on Google Cloud side right now, how can I obtain required keys?

Answer (score 1):

If you app is distributed outside of Play, I am afraid there is no option for the local decryption and verification.

Comment: So I should choose online verification than? But online verification is bound to Play console as well, so looks like it will not help